# Module inside module error, python

Tags: python, python-module

I created a File named StringPlay.py, and called it upon a file ScanTheFile.py then called a function in ScanTheFile.py in another file named Controller.py. But it raise an error that StringPlay.py does not exist

In ScanTheFile.py

```
import StringPlay as SP

def TNews(FileFirstLine):
    FileLine = SP.RemoveSpases(FileFirstLine)
    if True:
       Statement
    return(FileLine)
```

In Controller.py

```
from HelpFiles import StringPlay as SP
from HelpFiles import ScanTheFile as StF

File1 = open("TextFiles\File1.txt")
print(Stf.TNews(File1.readline()))
```

When this is executed it raises a Message Stating that in ScanTheFile.py in Line 1:

```
File "C:\Users\***\My Documents\Python\HelpFiles\ScanTheFile.py", line 1, in <module>
import StringPlay as SP
ImportError: No module named 'StringPlay'
```

But when ScanTheFile.py is being executed there's no problem.

This is my directory structure

```
My Documents\Python 
My Documents\Python\Controller.py 
My Documents\Python\HelpFiles 
My Documents\Python\HelpFiles\ScanTheFile.py 
My Documents\Python\HelpFiles\StringPlay.py 
My Documents\Python\TextFiles 
My Documents\Python\TextFiles\File1.txt 
My Documents\Python\TextFiles\File2.txt
```

Comment: Can you share the folder structure?

Comment: uhm, still new with all of this but will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this problem because when you run `Controller.py` you are running it in say `C:\...\My Documents` when you call `from HelpFiles import ScanTheFile as StF` you are telling python to look in `C:\...\My Documents\HelpFiles` for a file named `ScanTheFile.py`.

It finds this file and runs it *in `C:\...\My Documents`* so when it hits the line in `ScanTheFile.py`:

```
import StringPlay as SP
```

it looks in `C:\...\My Documents` for `StringPlay.py` which from what I can gather exists in `C:\...\My Documents\HelpFiles`.

Since you are already importing `StringPlay.py` explicitly in `Controller.py`  I would say just change `ScanTheFile.py` to only import `StringPlay.py` when it is the file being run directly, and not imported:

`ScanTheFile.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import StringPlay as SP

def TNews(FileFirstLine):
    FileLine = SP.RemoveSpases(FileFirstLine)
    if True:
       Statement
    return(FileLine)
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. I changed the     import StringPlay as SP to from HelpFiles import StringPlay as SP and it works. But leaving me with the problem that when I want to use the same File in another python file it will give me an error again and give me an error like this one

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Limitless sure, no problem!  The idea of the currently running directory ts a good thing to become familiar with.   There are many solutions to this problem.

Comment: @Limitless If you want to delve deeper, the solution \@Muctadir suggested is a good one to get familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing from `HelpFiles` which is basically a folder not a file. To put it simply, in python if you want to import something from a folder, it has to be a package unless you add the path to the folder to python path explicitly.

So, to solve the problem you are having make `HelpFiles` a package by putting an empty file with name `__init__.py` in that folder which should look something like this

```
.
└── My Document
    └── Python
        ├── Controller.py
        ├── HelpFiles
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── ScanTheFile.py
        │   └── StringPlay.py
        └── TextFiles
            ├── File1.txt
            └── File2.txt
```

Comment: Sorry still giving the same problem :(

Comment: You are executing the script from which folder?

Comment: My Docs\Python\Controller.py

Comment: That is the the File I am using to "Control" the other files. Like just tkinter interface etc then using the other functions in the other files

Comment: I created the same folder structure and executed `python My\ Document/Python/Controller.py`. Works perfectly for me. Check the structure in the answer

Comment: Mine is exactly like the Answer's and yet gives an error, can you maybe add the code you using? I might have slipped there

Comment: Well, I can not simulate your problem. It might be the case that you are actually having any other problem.